# How do I use an environment variable in a .cargo/config file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using `.cargo/config` like this

```
[target.arm-linux-androideabi]
linker = "/home/rico/android-ndk-r13b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
```

But `/home/rico/android-ndk-r13b` is my NDK_HOME, not NDK_HOME of everyone

How can I specify to use `$NDK_HOME`?

Something like:

```
[target.arm-linux-androideabi]
linker = "$NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
```

Answer (score 7):

`.cargo/config` doesn't support environment variables. But you can configure the linker with `RUSTC_LINKER` environment variable:

```
export RUSTC_LINKER="$NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
cargo build  # will try to use NDK's linker now
```

Though it'll work for all targets, not only for `arm-linux-androideabi`.

Comment: Any idea whether `.cargo/config` supports home directory (having difficulties finding this, probably not).

Comment: @lxx nope, as far as I know