# Is it possible to change the environment variables automatically when running cargo for rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need to switch the native compiler version often to compile my rust project. But it seems that cargo always uses the current `PATH` environment variable to find the corresponding `cc`, `ar`.

Can I specify my compiler directory in the cargo configuration file? I noticed in the manual that I can set environment variables via the `[env]` section, but given that I'm modifying the PATH, it has to be set to
`PATH=$PATH:/mycross/compiler/bin` which sets the new value based on the old one.

It seems that it is not supported. So what do I do? Do I have to write a bash script to set it up and call the relevant cargo command?

Also, I do not want to write it in my project's `build.rs` script. Because I have many dependences also need to use the same compiler.

Comment: I found a simliar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676757/how-do-i-use-an-environment-variable-in-a-cargo-config-file